# Button and PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

i have a code i want when i click button not set active (with PlayerPrefs) but problem when i run game a button not set active before i click it (button)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class fcfg : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject butt;

    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ButtonActivate") == 0)
        {
                butt.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ButtonActivate") == 1)
        {
                butt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    public void whenbuttonclick()
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ButtonActivate", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of your `SetActive` calls in `Start` pass false as their parameter. Should one of them be true? Should your click function toggle the button or always turn it off?

Comment: in parameter the first SetActive is true........ a toggle is on in inspector

Comment: It is now that you edited it. The only code that sets your PlayerPref sets it to 0. If it can never be 1 it doesn't really matter does it?

Comment: i change it to 1 button still not shown but when i change line  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ButtonActivate") == 0)
        {
                butt.gameObject.SetActive(false); to true button shown

Comment: It's hard to even guess what you're seeing when you keep changing the code.  Good luck.